# What is difference between network service and network interface

Tags: terminal, network, ethernet

I'm a little bit confused about the difference between a `network interface` and `network service`. For example, the `ifconfig` utility documentation talks in terms of the network interface:

> ifconfig en0

While "networksetup" is using network service:

> networksetup -getinfo %network service name%

Can a single network interface have multiple network services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`networksetup` is the CLI interface for network settings panel in System Preferences.  From the [`man page`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/networksetup.8.html):

> The networksetup command is used to configure network settings
>   typically configured in the System Preferences application.

`ifconfig` is the utility to set up a network interface.  From the [`man page`](https://ss64.com/bash/ifconfig.html)

> The ifconfig utility is used to assign an address to a network
>   interface and/or configure network interface parameters.

What you are seeing is two different methods with different nomenclature for the same thing.

`networksetup` is specific to macOS where `ifconfig` is more generic and part of the BSD core

As to your question...

> Can a single network interface have multiple network services?

Yes.  For instance, you can have an alias for that interface.  Using actual System Prefs (because it's visually easier), I created a new service called "Ask Different Demo" to my existing interface "Ethernet"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In computer networking, a network service is an application running at the network application layer and above, that provides data storage, manipulation, presentation, communication or other capability which is often implemented using a client-server or peer-to-peer architecture based on application layer network protocols.

Each service is usually provided by a server component running on one or more computers (often a dedicated server computer offering multiple services) and accessed via a network by client components running on other devices. However, the client and server components can both be run on the same machine.

Clients and servers will often have a user interface, and sometimes other hardware associated with it.